# Passing data from view to controller in dotnet core

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, .net-core

In my project, I need to have the ability to display data for a given range of dates on a web page.

My controller is this:

```
public JiraDashboardController(IOptions<Config> app)
{
    appSettings = app;
    _jira = Jira.CreateRestClient(appSettings.Value.BaseUrl, appSettings.Value.UserName,appSettings.Value.Password);
    _db = new UserDashboard(appSettings.Value.UserName, appSettings.Value.ProjectName, _jira);
    startDate = new DateTime(2019, 01, 01); // debugging purposes
    endDate = new DateTime(2019, 02, 11);  // debugging purposes
}

public ActionResult Index(DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate)
{
    ViewData["OpenedIssues"] = _db.IssuesOpenedInRange(fromDate, toDate);
        ViewData["ClosedIssues"] = _db.IssuesClosedInRange(fromDate, toDate);

    return View();
}
```

And the corresponding view:

```
@model MyProject.Models.Jiras

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
<h3>Total issues opened: @ViewData["OpenedIssues"]</h3>
<h3>Total issues closed: @ViewData["ClosedIssues"]</h3>

<div>
    <p>From Date: <input type="text" id="fromdate"></p>
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<div>
    <p>To Date: <input type="text" id="toDate"></p>
</div>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#fromdate").datepicker();
        $("#toDate").datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

I'm using, what I assume, is a [standard jQuery date picker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) but I don't know the best way to then get my selected value back into the method.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do as follows:

```
<form asp-controller="YourControllerName" asp-action="Index" method="post">
        <div>
            <p>From Date: <input type="text" id="fromdate" name="fromDate"></p>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <div>
            <p>To Date: <input type="text" id="toDate" name="toDate"></p>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```

Don't forget to add a *_ViewIports.cshtml* in your Views folder and add the following code, this enables tag helpers.

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

Don't forget to add name for your inputs as well as I've done.
Model binding will handle converting string into Date.